# Is there a temperature limit for the magneto-caloric effect?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, dissipation

Suppose a thermally insulated box which has to keep its inner temperature below a certain limit, and suppose a high temperature outside of the box, such as a fire at 1000C.

Would it be possible to create a magneto-caloric device which make its heatsink reach a temperature higher than the temperature outside of the box? i.e, 1500C in the heatsink while the ambient temperature is 1000C ?

Is there a theoretical limit for the magnetocaloric effect?
Could it be used as a cooling system for devices in extreme environments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems which preclude this from working, there is no hard theoretical limit but there are many engineering limitations due to the physics "not working hard enough".

Magneto-caloric refrigeration uses a magnet to corral the spins, forcing them to align with the magnetic field. This is similar to a compressor in ordinary refrigeration, which uses a piston to force gas molecules into a smaller space instead of forcing spins into smaller range of angles. 
Magneto-caloric refrigeration is used at liquid helium temperatures, where the thermal energy is hundreds or thousands of times less than room temperature.

It is not practical even for 77K (-196 C) liquid nitrogen much much less 1000C. Why is this? *The corralling force is very low*. Any magnets much stronger than a Neodymium magnet will require very expensive liquid helium or extreme power consumption. A neodymium magnetic attracting a ferrous material is the amount of corralling energy you have to work with, approximately speaking. But this energy is still dwarfed by the thermal energy, which is equivalent to shooting the iron at nearly the speed of a bullet. Even a neo magnet has no hope catching a paperclip "bullet" at hundreds of meters/second, so it can't significantly corral spins that are jostled by thermal motions at these speeds. There are some materials that have an unusually strong coupling, so called "giant magneto-caloric effects", but they are still beaten out by vapor compression.

Refrigeration is difficult under extreme conditions. Temperature is *defined* as how little entropy is changed as thermal energy is added/removed: T = dU/dS, where U is energy and S is entropy. T must be in in an absolute temperature scale such as kelvin. Heat wants to flows from hot to cold because dS = dU/T, so removing some energy dU from a hot source costs less entropy than the entropy gained by adding it to a cold source. How much energy does it take to transfer one joule from 1000C to 1500C? The extra energy we put in, E, will be transferred to the hot source. Total entropy can not drop, so the best we can hope for is for the total dS to be zero: dS_total = (dU+E)/1773 - dU/1273 = 0. Solving for E we get E = 0.39J. Your example is a greater ratio than most air-conditioners and refrigerators/freezers, so it is fighting a more-uphill battle than your Kenmore, where E would be at most 0.1 or so.

In an ideal world with perfect machines, need to supply 40% of the energy that will be transferred away from the 1000C waste-heat source. Engineering limitations bite down hard for *any* refrigeration system, especially one forced to work at such a high temperature, so you are looking at E>1J most likely. This still could be useful, for example E=2J means that every for two joules of electricity you get three joules of heat added to the 1500C block, an efficiency of 150%. But another problem is heat will try *very hard* to get back to the cooler 1000C waste-heat bath and from both the heat sink and 1000C bath to your machinery (you don't plan on having motors operate at 1000C do you?). This could doom any real-world gains over just heating the block with a flame or element even considering all heat-pump methods.

Answer (score 0):

The true limits are twofolds from my understanding;

The first one is an engineering problem, as it will be hard to create or complete a machine that will work fine under extreme conditions.

The second is material. We have not found yet materials that generate a great-enough change of entropy at high enough temperature. In addition, one would need to verify the competition between environnemental influence/input (related to T, $T_o$, $c_v$, $\tau$, K$_b$) in terms of energy vs the change in energy/temperature produced by the magnetocaloric effect of a given crystal (linked to T, T$_o$, $c_v$, $\tau$, M, $\mathbf{B}$, K$_b$). In brief, it wouldn't be an easy task. For the liquifaction of N, we use paramagnetic salt with magnetocaloric effect, which is quite impressive ;) .

However, as the last answer said, TOTAL entropy cannot drop, but you can play a lot with magnetic entropy which is key for MCE and RMCE (magnetocaloric effect and rotative magnetocaloric effect), that's how you get the thermal change (if we'd solely go with the total entropy argument, EMC and EMCR would be impossible btw). In addition, heat flows from higher to lower temperature elements as the system wants to minimise its total energy state (using the entropy to explain it is another way of seeing it, but is not as general). One would need a material with a very high "magnetization potential" (or a very large change in magnetization for a low magnetic field) and a very large difference of magnetization between its magnetized state (max M) and non magnetized state (min M), which is rare at high temperature (above 200K. Hell, even above 100K). However, thin films and new compounds are more and more promising/interesting (recent thin films were presenting 1K change for 1T if I recall correctly, but I can be wrong it is from memory here) for room temperature applications (though I doubt we'd have anough material for a commercial fridge unfortunately).

In short, to answer you question, in theory, there are no "limits" per say, all depends on the material and the enginners. As for the extreme temperature condition, once again the problem is on the engineer side of things rather than the physics, as we haven't found a crystal or compund that could even work at room temperature, let alone 1000C. But if one would find such crystal that can present sufficient high change in M at these temperature and large $T_C$ (500K is way to large, you'd need multiple cristal with different T$_c$ varying from 1273K to 1773K). On paper, yeah it could be feasable, but I doubt it could be done in practice.

Hope it helps, cheers.